# Rendering error with Native-base and Swiper

Tags: react-native, native-base, react-native-swiper

I've been following this tutorial here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pgDOpIm6ozQ(#1 Snapchat UI Swipe Animation | React Native Layouts - Expo and Native Base)

However when I run it on expo it only shows a blank screen and I checked if  there's any problem related to compatibility between versions and i didn't found anything
[My Android Emulator Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0ut8.png)

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { Container, Content } from 'native-base';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  slideDefault: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#9DD6EB'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }
})
export default class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      outerScrollEnabled: true
    }
  }

  verticalScroll = (index) => {
    if (index !== 1) {
      this.setState({
        outerScrollEnabled: false
      })
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        outerScrollEnabled: true
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Swiper
            loop={false}
            showsPagination={false}
            index={1}
            scrollEnabled={this.state.outerScrollEnabled}
          >

            <View style={styles.slideDefault}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Chat</Text>
            </View>
            <Swiper
              loop={false}
              showsPagination={false}
              horizontal={false}
              index={1}
              onIndexChanged={(index) => this.verticalScroll(index)}
            >
              <View style={styles.slideDefault}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Search</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.slideDefault}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Camera</Text>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.slideDefault}>
                <Text style={styles.text}>Memories</Text>
              </View>
            </Swiper>
            <View style={styles.slideDefault}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>Stories</Text>
            </View>
          </Swiper>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

```js
{
  "name": "empty-project-template",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^30.0.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-30.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.13",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.1.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried updating your native base? also you might want to try a quick copy and paste of his code https://github.com/nathvarun/React-Native-Layout-Tutorial-Series/tree/master/Project%20Files/05.%20%231%20Snapchat%20Swipe%20UI Otherwise i cant seem to notice anything wrong